# How to set dynamic url in React Native 'Share' function

Tags: javascript, react-native, dynamic, share

I'm referencing one of my props, a url (but in plain object form), in the Share component of React Native.  I've tried several different ways to get Share to actual be able to read it.  None have worked.  And they should....anyone see what I'm missing?

Here's the code:

```
onShareButtonPress() {
   const { image } = this.props.employee;
   const test = JSON.stringify(image);
     //console.log(test);
   Share.share({
      message: 'Here\'s your image:',
      url: test,
      title: 'Dealerslist Image'
   }, {
      // Android only:
      dialogTitle: 'Share Dealerslist goodness',
      // iOS only:
      excludedActivityTypes: [
       'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'
     ]
   })
```

This won't work either:

```
 url: 'image',
```

If I log 'test' I get the url as the expected string.  But Share still can't recognize it.  But if I copy the string straight from the console and hardcode/paste it in as the url, it works perfectly.

This code works:

```
Share.share({
message: 'Here\'s your image:',
url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ag-equipment-
      southwest.appspot.com/o/1512760876838.4595.jpg?
      alt=media&token=1bfeba0d-d788-4774-91a7-7801c8084b30",
title: 'Dealerslist Image'
```

}

And 'test' logs exactly as:

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ag-equipment-
southwest.appspot.com/o/1512760876838.4595.jpg?
alt=media&token=1bfeba0d-d788-4774-91a7-7801c8084b30"
```

All of these I've tried with sharing to ios mail. And the dynamic link won't work with the mail.

However, if I just share to the ios clipboard, I get this:

```
 Here's your image:%22https://firebasestorage....and so on
```

I'm new to web and mobile development, so I'm not totally sure if the expected behavior is to copy '%22' as possibly a break in the line.  Regardless, the ios mail share isn't getting any of the url.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why the `JSON.stringify`? Try removing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `JSON.stringify` on a string which will add two quotes at the start and end.

`" = %22` which probably is the reason for the extra `%22` codes

```
onShareButtonPress() {
   const { image } = this.props.employee;
   Share.share({
      message: 'Here\'s your image:',
      url: image,
      title: 'Dealerslist Image'
   }
   .
   .
   .
)
```

But ideally you would want to try `encodeURI` and `decodeURI` if you don't want to deal with unexpected characters during the request flight.

[**URL ENCODING LIST**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

[**ENCODE URI**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

[**DECODE URI**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

```js
const url = "https://google.com"

console.log(url);

console.log(JSON.stringify(url));
```

Comment: Thanks Nandu! That worked.  I was trying that earlier, but something else must've been wrong, cuz just image wasn't working then.  Thanks a million!